# Tier price is not display on product view page and not apply into cart page also

Tags: product-view, ce-1.9.2.2, tierprice

[image][image]

I had applied tier price on products it save data in 
    `mage_catalog_product_entity_tier_price` database table but it does not show any effect of tier price on view and list page of Website.

```
<?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml()  ?>
```

Does not print and label

Comment: How did you setup the admin? Can you share a screenshot of admin and frontend? Also update the magento version.

Comment: try to remove cache folder and then check. Also do reindexing from admin.

Comment: I tried this but not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Tier price should be lower than special price.
2. Special price should be lower than Regular price (Price).
3. No need to modify any files to show tier price at the listing and detailed page

Example:

[image]